# String substition using sed

Tags: string, bash, sed

```
while read p
    do
       p_upper=`echo $p | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'`  
       echo $p_upper:$p
       sed "s/$p_uper/$p/g" billpay-package.txt
    done < methods.txt
```

I am reading string line by line from file methods.txt (these strings are in camel case) being assigned to variable p , then converting these strings to uppercase and storing them in p_upper as shown above , what i want to do is , replace the uppercase instances with camel-case instance in file:billpay-package.xml but it appears as if sed command is not executing properly

Comment: You probably need: `sed -i.bak "s/$p_uper/$p/g" billpay-package.txt` to inline edit the input file.

Comment: And `$p_uper` is not the same as `$p_upper`.  But maybe that's just a typo in the question.

Comment: If you're not using a Mac, you can do the in-place modification `sed -i` as suggested above (if that's the issue).  On a Mac, you'll have to direct the output to a file.  The script seems to work fine except for `p_uper` being the match (should be `p_upper`).

Comment: that wasnt a type i made a mistake , the shell script did run to completion but there wasnt any desired output on the cyg-win console window or the source file , adding -i flag did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're executing `sed` but not saving the output. Use `sed -i`.

In bash, you can convert a variable to uppercase using the shorter-form shown below:

```
while read p
do
    p_upper=${p^^}
    sed -i "s/$p_upper/$p/g" billpay-package.txt
done < methods.txt
```